# How can I remove marker with bonded circle from the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I did bind the circle  with marker to make view like:

[image]

But when I try to remove marker from the map, the circle still exists. Hmm,

How can I remove marker with circle?

**Relevant code:**

```
 function removeMarker(){
    if(selectedMarker)
       selectedMarker.setMap(null);      
}

....

function createCircle()
{
                var circle = {
                strokeColor: "#006DFC",
                strokeOpacity: 0.4,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#006DFC",
                fillOpacity: 0.15,
                map: mapA,
                center: selectedMarker.getPosition(),
                radius: 50 // in meters
            };
            var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circle);    


            cityCircle.bindTo('center', selectedMarker, 'position');
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the Circle when you remove the marker, you need to remove it also.

```
 cityCircle.setMap(null);
```

You will need to keep a reference to the circle to do that (not tested):

```
function removeMarker(){
  if(selectedMarker)
    selectedMarker.setMap(null); 
    selectedMarker._mycityCircle.unbindAll();
    selectedMarker._mycityCircle.setMap(null);  
}

....

function createCircle()
{
  var circle = {
    strokeColor: "#006DFC",
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#006DFC",
    fillOpacity: 0.15,
    map: mapA,
    center: selectedMarker.getPosition(),
    radius: 50 // in meters
  };

  cityCircle.bindTo('center', selectedMarker, 'position');
  selectedMarker._mycityCircle = cityCircle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. `_myCircle` dosn't have method  `setMap`. I didn't place `circle` on the map only bind to marker.