# How to remove previous circle automatically before adding new circle in Google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to remove the first circle before adding a new circle click on the marker of Google map.

I am using google map API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

Website Link: http://premium-gates.com/bft/dealers/

Search text for testing: 5427DG

**Here is the code of adding circle on the marker.**

```js
function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
    var image = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/map-pin.png';

    var html = "<div class='map-popup'><b>" + name + "</b> <p>" + address + "</p></div>";
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: image
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
        addCircle(event.latLng);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

function addCircle(location) {
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 0.2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        map: map,
        center: location,
        radius: 1000,
        draggable:false
    });
}
```

How do I remove the circle before add a new one when I click on the marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related questions:

- [How can I remove marker with bonded circle from the map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006156/how-can-i-remove-marker-with-bonded-circle-from-the-map)
- [Remove a circle object from a Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299598/remove-a-circle-object-from-a-google-map)

If you only ever want a single circle, keep a reference to it and remove it (if it exists) before creating the new one.  Add this:

```
if (cityCircle && cityCircle.setMap) 
  cityCircle.setMap(null);
```

To the `addCircle` funciton:

```
var cityCircle;
function addCircle(location) {
  if (cityCircle && cityCircle.setMap)
    cityCircle.setMap(null);
  cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0.2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    map: map,
    center: location,
    radius: 1000,
    draggable: false
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/59yurhxb/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    }
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  setMarkers(map);
}

var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    createMarker({
      lat: beach[1],
      lng: beach[2]
    }, beach[0], beach[0]);
  }
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {

  var html = "<div class='map-popup'><b>" + name + "</b> <p>" + address + "</p></div>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
    addCircle(event.latLng);
  });

  markers.push(marker);
}

var cityCircle;

function addCircle(location) {
  if (cityCircle && cityCircle.setMap)
    cityCircle.setMap(null);
  cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0.2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    map: map,
    center: location,
    radius: 1000,
    draggable: false
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```